# DAX pick a value from tied resultset

Tags: filter, calculated-columns, dax

i need help with the following dax statement.

**Situation:**
I have 2 tables. One table contains sell data with articleIDs, dateIDs and sell prices, another table contains stock movements data with articleIDs, dateIDs and purchase prices. According to the dateID i want to write the purchase prices into the first table using a calculated column because i need the prices for every row.

Example:

#### Table1 t1

- t1.articleID = 123; t1.dateID = 20160905; t1.sellPrice = 62,55; t1.purchasePrice = *My DAX Statement*

#### Table2 t2

- t2.articleID = 123; t2.dateID = 20160905; t2.purchasePrice = 37,07
- t2.articleID = 123; t2.dateID = 20160905; t2.purchasePrice = 37,07
- t2.articleID = 123; t2.dateID = 20160906; t2.purchasePrice = 37,07
- t2.articleID = 456; t2.dateID = 20160905; t2.purchasePrice = 12,15

#### My DAX Statement:

```
= CALCULATE (
    VALUES (t2[purchasePrice]);
        TOPN (
            1; 
            FILTER(FILTER(t2; t2[articleID] = t1[articleID]); t2[dateID] <= t1[dateID]); t2[dateID]; DESC
                  )
        )
```

With my DAX Statement i get the following error: 
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

It is normal that i have more than one row matching in the table 2. 
Actually I just want the price of any of them on the corresponding dateID, even if they are tied. So i used the TOPN function with the value 1 and sorted by date but the error still remains. Is there a way to fix my DAX Statement to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a calculated column in T1 and use this expression:

```
purchasePrice =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( T2[purchasePrice] ),
    FILTER ( T2, T1[ArticleID] = T2[articleID] && T1[DateID] = T2[dateID] )
)
```

Note I use comma to separate passed arguments to the functions but I see in your expression you used semicolon. Change it to match your system list separator.

It is not tested but should work. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, the max function instead of the values function did the magic :)